# Can I specify relative URL when using jQuery.get?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm trying to make an ajax call like so:

```
 $.get('/home/myInfo', function (data)

     {

        ....

     });
```

I'm calling it from a page that is at: http://localhost/myapp/home/index

When I try to make the above call, it goes to: http://localhost/myapp/home/index/home/myInfo

I want it to go to http://localhost/myapp/home/myInfo

Do I have to specify absolute URL?

Comment: did you try with simply "myInfo" or "../myInfo" ?

Comment: i tried myInfo then i get http://localhost/myapp/home/index/myinfo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Absolutely never hardcode urls like this in an ASP.NET MVC application. Always use URL helpers when dealing with urls, like this:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("MyInfo", "Home")', function (data) {
    ....
});
```

or if this is in a separate javascript file where you cannot use server side helpers, well you could for example use HTML 5 data-* attributes on some DOM element tat you are AJAXifying, like a div or something:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-url="@Url.Action("MyInfo", "Home")">Click me</div>
```

and then:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function() {
    $.get($(this).data('url'), function (data) {
        ....
    });
});
```

or if you are AJAXifying a form or an anchor:

```
$('#myanchor').click(function() {
    $.get(this.href, function (data) {
        ....
    });
    return false;
});
```

where the anchor would of course have been generated using helpers:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "MyInfo", "Home", null, new { id = "myanchor" })
```

See? No need to hardcode urls. Don't do it as it will break at the very second you modify the pattern of your routes in `Global.asax`. By following this technique your code will be totally agnostic to any changes of the structure of your routes.

Comment: Ah yes, I knew there must be a better way. Thank you.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting explaining the reasoning behind it.

Comment: WRT hardcoding URLs: It always frustrates me that OOB helper methods are not intellisense-aware. "MyInfo" & "Home" are always magic strings. ReSharper helps with this, but still leaves potential to have unbounded action urls

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have copied and pasted the code correctly?  Because as you have it, that should be referencing http://localhost/home/myInfo .  The only reason I could see it doing as you have described is if your code was using a relative url like this:

```
 $.get('home/myInfo', function (data)

     {

        ....

     });
```

Otherwise, if you're truly using the value "/home/myInfo" instead of "home/myInfo" , you already are referencing the absolute version of the url (the definition of an "absolute" url being that it starts with "/").   I ran some quick tests, and on my local machine, using "/home/myInfo" yields an XHR request to http://localhost/home/myInfo